# AXL Java UpdatePhoneReq for CUCM 10.5 executes with no errors but doesnt change the phone

Tags: java, eclipse, cisco-axl

Newbie to eclipse - AXL - Java

I am inching my way forward to learn the above.

using JavaSE 1.8, and eclipse 4.13.0, to interact with a lab call manager running v 10.5,
and by following and modifying a demo, Ive been able to successfully run a getphone to return information about a phone - including UUID and description.

From there Im attempting to add a 'setphone' section to change just the phone description, then display the phone information again.

Everything runs fine, with no errors, but the description never changes.

This is the code I'm using:

```
package com.cisco.axl.demo; 

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

/**
 * ------------ AXL DEMO 4 ------------
* Intro - THIS VERSION AXLD3 WORKS on Laptop!!!
*/

import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;

import com.cisco.axlapiservice.AXLAPIService;
import com.cisco.axlapiservice.AXLError;
import com.cisco.axlapiservice.AXLPort;
import com.cisco.axl.api._10.*;


/**
* 
 * Performs getPhone operation using AXL API
* 
 * Note, service consumers were generated by the Java 6 wsimport command:
* 
 * <code>
* wsimport -keep -b schema/current/AXLSOAP.xsd -Xnocompile -s src -d bin -verbose schema/current/AXLAPI.ws
* </code>
* 
 * Since AXL uses HTTPS you will have to install the UC application's 
 * Certificate into your keystore in order to run this sample code
* 
 * you can run the program by cd'ing to bin folder within this project and running the following command
* 
 * <code>
* java -cp . com.cisco.axl.demo.Demo
*</code>
*
* it is necessary to install the target systems ssl certificate to all JRE and JDK
* certificate stores - for JREs use:
* "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin\keytool" -import -alias LabCertJre16 -file "C:\Apps\USFEL1-UCL201_corp_pattersoncompanies_com.crt" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre<VER>\lib\security\jssecacerts"
* 
 * for JDKs use:
* "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin\keytool" -import -alias LabCertJre16 -file "C:\Apps\USFEL1-UCL201_corp_pattersoncompanies_com.crt" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk<VER>\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
*
*/

/*
 /*
Things to fix
password is exposed
cert requires fqdn - need to support IP and just server name
warning at beginning
 */

public class Demo {
                /**
                * UC app host.
                */
                protected static String ucHost = null;

                /**
                * OS admin.
                */
                protected static String ucAdmin = null;

                /**
                * OS admin password.
                */
                protected static String ucPswd = null;

                /**
                * New Description.
                */
                protected static String ucDescr = null;

                /**
                * phoneName used in request.
                */
                protected static String phoneName = null;

                /**
                * phoneName used in request.
                */
                protected static String NewDescription = null;

                /**
                 *  UUID returned from getphone - used in setphone
                 */
                protected static String PhoneUUID = null;

                /**
                * Run the demo
                * 
                 * @param args not used
                */
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                                // Verify JVM has a console
                                if (System.console() == null) {
                                                System.err.println("The Cisco AXL Sample App requires a console.");
                                                System.exit(1);
                                } else {
                                                Demo.informUser("%nWelcome to the Cisco AXL Sample APP .%n");
                                }

                                Demo demo = new Demo();
                                demo.getPhoneInfo();



                }

                /**
                * get information about phone
                */
                public void getPhoneInfo() {
                                // Ask for the UC application to upgrade
                                // Demo.informuser("%nWhat UC server would you like to access?%n");
                                ucHost = promptUser("  Host:  ");
                                ucAdmin = promptUser("  OS Admin Account:  ");
                                ucPswd = promptUser("  OS Admin Password:  ");

                                // Ask for the phone name
                                Demo.informUser("%nEnter the name of the phone you want to retrieve information about.%n");
                                phoneName = promptUser("  Phone Name:  ");

                                // Make the getPhoneRequest
                                getPhone();
                                SetPhoneDescr();
                                getPhone();

                }

/**
                   * Makes the getPhone request and displays some of the fields that are returned.
                */
                private void getPhone() 
                                {

                                // Instantiate the wsimport generated AXL API Service client --
                                // see the wsimport comments in the class javadocs above
                                AXLAPIService axlService = new AXLAPIService();
                                AXLPort axlPort = axlService.getAXLPort();


                                // Set the URL, user, and password on the JAX-WS client
                                String validatorUrl = "https://"
                                    + Demo.ucHost
                                    + ":8443/axl/";


                                ((BindingProvider) axlPort).getRequestContext().put(
                                    BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, validatorUrl);
                                ((BindingProvider) axlPort).getRequestContext().put(
                                    BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, Demo.ucAdmin);
                                ((BindingProvider) axlPort).getRequestContext().put(
                                    BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, Demo.ucPswd);

                                // Create a GetPhoneReq object to represent the getPhone request and set the name of the device
                                //to name entered by user
                                GetPhoneReq axlParams = new GetPhoneReq();
                                axlParams.setName(phoneName);

                                //Make a call to the AXL Service and pass the getPhone request
                                GetPhoneRes getPhoneResponse = null;
                                try {
                                                getPhoneResponse = axlPort.getPhone(axlParams);
                                } catch (AXLError e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                //display information returned in the response to the user
//                            Demo.informUser("Product=" + getPhoneResponse.getReturn().getPhone().getProduct() + "%n"
//                    + getPhoneResponse.getReturn().getPhone().getLoadInformation().getValue() + "%n");

                                Demo.informUser("Product=" + getPhoneResponse.getReturn().getPhone().getProduct() + "%n");

                                Demo.informUser("Load=" + getPhoneResponse.getReturn().getPhone().getLoadInformation().getValue() + "%n");

                                Demo.informUser("Descr=" + getPhoneResponse.getReturn().getPhone().getDescription()            + "%n");

                                Demo.informUser("Model=" + getPhoneResponse.getReturn().getPhone().getModel()           + "%n");

                                Demo.informUser("Name=" + getPhoneResponse.getReturn().getPhone().getName()          + "%n");

                                PhoneUUID = getPhoneResponse.getReturn().getPhone().getUuid();
                                Demo.informUser("UUID=" + PhoneUUID          + "%n");


                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println(" ");

                                }


                public void SetPhoneDescr() {



                    // Ask for the new description to apply to the phone
                      ucDescr = promptUser("  NewDescription:  ");


                    // Instantiate the wsimport generated AXL API Service client --
                    // see the wsimport comments in the class javadocs above
                    AXLAPIService axlService = new AXLAPIService();
                    AXLPort axlPort = axlService.getAXLPort();

                    // Set the URL, user, and password on the JAX-WS client
                    String validatorUrl = "https://"
                        + Demo.ucHost
                        + ":8443/axl/";


                    ((BindingProvider) axlPort).getRequestContext().put(
                        BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, validatorUrl);
                    ((BindingProvider) axlPort).getRequestContext().put(
                        BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, Demo.ucAdmin);
                    ((BindingProvider) axlPort).getRequestContext().put(
                        BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, Demo.ucPswd);



                                // Create a GetPhoneReq object to represent the getPhone request and set the name of the device
                                //to name entered by user
                                UpdatePhoneReq axlParams = new UpdatePhoneReq();
                                axlParams.setNewName(phoneName);
                                axlParams.setDescription(NewDescription);
                                axlParams.setName(phoneName);
                                axlParams.setUuid(PhoneUUID);


                                /**
                                /**
                                 * some test code from devnet Support on JAXBElement

//                                String username = null;
                                String device_uuid = null;

                                axlParams.setUuid(device_uuid);   //.setUuid(device_uuid);
                                    XFkType user = new XFkType(); 
                                    user.setUuid(PhoneUUID);  //returns UserUUID 
                                    JAXBElement<XFkType> user2 = new JAXBElement(new QName(XFkType.class.getSimpleName()), XFkType.class, user);


                                 * end of sample code from devnet
                                 */



                                //Make a call to the AXL Service and pass the getPhone request
                                StandardResponse UpdatePhoneRes = null;
                                try {
                                    UpdatePhoneRes = axlPort.updatePhone(axlParams);
                    } catch (AXLError e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }




                }


// -------------------- Some I/O Helper Methods ------------------------

                /**
                * Provide the user some instructions.
    */
                protected static void informUser(String info) {
                                System.console().format(info);
                }


                /**
                * Ask the user a question
                     * @return A non-null, non-empty answer to the question
     */
protected static String promptUser(String question){
   String answer = null;
   while (answer == null || answer.isEmpty()) {
      answer = System.console().readLine(question);
   }
   return answer.trim();
}
}
```

The main question is, why isnt it updating the description? 
I saw a previous post that indicated I needed to call an 'apply' but I didnt see a method for that.
When I looked at the AXL log for the attempt it showed this as the XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:updatePhone xmlns:ns2="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/10.5"><name>SEP00AF1F9C5D7A</name><newName>SEP00AF1F9C5D7A</newName></ns2:updatePhone></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

clearly the xlParams.setDescription(NewDescription); is not passing the param - just as clearly I dont know too much about what Im doing yet.

Any help you can give on that question would be much appreciated.

Also, when I first started working on the 'set' part of this, I thought I wouldnt have to set up the connection a second time, since it was set up in the 'get' part. However I found it necessary to repeat it. Is this because it was in the getphone section instead of the main, or must it be set up everytime?

Also, everytime I run it (once for the get, once for the set, then again for the second get), I get this error:

WARNING: Import of file:/C:/Users/ME/eclipse-workspace/axl-demo/schema/current/AXLSoap.xsd is violation of BP 1.1 R2001. Proceeding with a warning.
R2001 A DESCRIPTION must only use the WSDL "import" statement to import another WSDL description.

Posts Ive found suggest this is a problem in the web service itself rather than my code: is this correct? Is there a way to suppress it in this enviroment?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're setting both 'name' and 'uuid' in the updatePhone request - these are used to identify the target device, and you should specify one or the other.

Looking at your code, the 'phoneName' variable is likely to be empty just here, and it may be that AXL is ignoring your (valid) uuid value and attempting to update a target device with an empty name...

Comment: Thanks David - my screen didnt show your post before I posted. Any ideas on either of the secondary questions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It turned out to be a simple programming error rather than an AXL problem, etc. I populated one variable when prompting the user: ucDescr = promptUser("  NewDescription:  ")

but updated the phone build with the original description variable - so it was probably working the whole time - but setting the description back to its original value.

So for anyone finding this question in the future - nothing fancy or magical - just check the basics